# Combobox not behaving as expected after data is saved

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a form where the controls are bound to a simple DTO through a bindingsource. One particular control is a dropdown list and the binding is:

```
this.cboCustomer.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedValue", this.bindingSource, "CustomerId", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
this.cboCustomer.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.bindingSource, "CustomerName", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

It has 2 bindings because I'm updating 2 properties of the object.

I also have an event:

```
private void cboCustomer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var customer= cboCustomer.SelectedItem as Customer;
    if (customer == null)
        return;

    myObject.AccountNumber = customer.AccountNumber;
}
```

I enter all relevant information and save the entity. After saving, I set the bindingsource's datasource to a new instance, ie:

```
bindingSource.DataSource = myObject = new MyObject();
```

However, after the first time, when I select an item from the dropdown, the `SelectedItem` property is always null, even though there are items in the list.

I have to click on a different control, enter something there, and then the selection in the dropdown appears.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the `Binding` has an overload to add the initial selected value as parameter?

Comment: @Stefan There is an overload where one can set the nullValue (and which I'm not using):

Comment: Do you have binding errors in the logs / debugoutput?

Comment: How you added items to the combobox?

Comment: @Fabio By using an IList<Customer> as the datasource. Set once and never change, unless the form is completely cleared.

Comment: Why you need bind `CustomerName` as well? I think it should display correct name based on given `SelectedValue`. I try to understand purpose of your combobox in relation to `MyObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the 2 bindings on the control. The binding to the `Text` property was removed and the combobox now behaves as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical issue in WinForms bindings. To deal with it you can use the following pattern anywhere when you might need to reset a binding:

```
private MyObject myObject;

// gets or sets the currently bound object
public MyObject MyObject
{
    get
    {
        return myObject;
    }
    set
    {
        myObject = value;

        myObjectBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
        myObjectBindingSource.EndEdit();

        // rebind
        myObjectBindingSource.DataSource = null;
        myObjectBindingSource.DataSource = myObject;

        myObjectBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
        myObjectBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
    }
}
```

And then, instead of

```
bindingSource.DataSource = myObject = new MyObject();
```

just set the new property:

```
MyObject = new MyObject();
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. Same issue as before.